# Geth console - list active RPC connections

Tags: go-ethereum

Is it possible to list open `RPC` connections (to instances of `MetaMask`, for example) on a `Geth` node console?

Answer (score 0):

RPC is build on top of HTTP, HTTP it's a **request-response** protocol, it doesnt hold connections.

Comment: is it possible to list rpc requests?